# Matching $ (dollar sign) words in Dart regular expression

Tags: regex, dart

I want to match all dollar sign words in the text. For example, `"Hello $VARONE this is $VARTWO"`, would match `$VARONE` and `$VARTWO`.

The regex should be `/\$(\w+)/g` but when I use this in Dart with the compiler in DartPad (https://dartpad.dartlang.org/) the words are not matched.

```
void main() {
  final variableGroupRegex = new RegExp(r"/\$(\w+)/g");

  Iterable<Match> matches = variableGroupRegex.allMatches("Hello \$VARONE this is \$VARTWO");
    for (Match match in matches) {
         print("match $match"); // code is never run as no matches
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may fix it as

```
final variableGroupRegex = new RegExp(r"\$(\w+)");

Iterable<Match> matches = variableGroupRegex.allMatches("Hello \$VARONE this is \$VARTWO");
for (Match match in matches) {
     print(match.group(0));
     print(match.group(1));
}
```

Output:

```
$VARONE
VARONE
$VARTWO
VARTWO
```

Here, you define the regex with a raw string literal, and `r"\$(\w+)` defines the `\$(\w+)` pattern. Then, to access the whole match, you may use `.group(0)` and to grab the captured value, use `.group(1)`.

Comment: I have a TextFormField(inputFormatters: [
                      FilteringTextInputFormatter.allow(
                          RegExp("^[2-9]{1}[0-9]{3}[0-9]{4}[0-9]{4}$")),
                    ],) but this regular expression not working and giving dollar "$" sign issue. Kindly suggest how can I solve it. Thanks.

Comment: @Kamlesh Use `RegExp(r"^[2-9]\d{11}$")`

Comment: Thanks Wiktor for your quick reply. I have updated code as you suggested inputFormatters: [
                      FilteringTextInputFormatter.allow(
                          RegExp(r"^[2-9]\d{1}[0-9]\d{3}[0-9]\d{4}[0-9]\d{4}$")),
                      LengthLimitingTextInputFormatter(12),
                    ], but I am not able to type anything in the textbox. Any suggestion. Thanks.

Comment: @Kamlesh This is a different question. Please consider asking it.

Comment: Wiktor, question is still same that RegEx (regular expression) is not working, please help

Comment: This regex restricting user to enter any data.